# Importing a tab-separated table from a url to produce a pandas dataframe with each column correctly put into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, import

I have a table of automotive data located at a URL. The data appears to be tab-separated. Here is the URL:

```
auto_table = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data'
```

And here are a few lines of the data:

```
18.0   8   307.0      130.0      3504.      12.0   70  1    "chevrolet chevelle malibu"
15.0   8   350.0      165.0      3693.      11.5   70  1    "buick skylark 320"
18.0   8   318.0      150.0      3436.      11.0   70  1    "plymouth satellite"
16.0   8   304.0      150.0      3433.      12.0   70  1    "amc rebel sst"
17.0   8   302.0      140.0      3449.      10.5   70  1    "ford torino"
15.0   8   429.0      198.0      4341.      10.0   70  1    "ford galaxie 500"
```

I have attempted to use pandas.read_table('auto_table') to import the data as a pandas dataframe. However, Python imports the data into just 2 columns: the first imported column contains all of these number/float/integer columns, and the second column correctly contains all of the strings (the names of automobiles).

How can I import this data using Python to produce a pandas dataframe with all of these data correctly separated into their own unique columns. I've checked out the documentation for pandas.read_table, [which is here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_table.html), but I can't seem to figure out how to properly import the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a fixed-width file, so we can use [pandas.read_fwf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
In [7]: df = pd.read_fwf(auto_table, header=None)

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
        0  1      2      3       4     5   6  7                            8
0    18.0  8  307.0  130.0  3504.0  12.0  70  1  "chevrolet chevelle malibu"
1    15.0  8  350.0  165.0  3693.0  11.5  70  1          "buick skylark 320"
2    18.0  8  318.0  150.0  3436.0  11.0  70  1         "plymouth satellite"
3    16.0  8  304.0  150.0  3433.0  12.0  70  1              "amc rebel sst"
4    17.0  8  302.0  140.0  3449.0  10.5  70  1                "ford torino"
5    15.0  8  429.0  198.0  4341.0  10.0  70  1           "ford galaxie 500"
6    14.0  8  454.0  220.0  4354.0   9.0  70  1           "chevrolet impala"
..    ... ..    ...    ...     ...   ...  .. ..                          ...
391  36.0  4  135.0  84.00  2370.0  13.0  82  1          "dodge charger 2.2"
392  27.0  4  151.0  90.00  2950.0  17.3  82  1           "chevrolet camaro"
393  27.0  4  140.0  86.00  2790.0  15.6  82  1            "ford mustang gl"
394  44.0  4   97.0  52.00  2130.0  24.6  82  2                  "vw pickup"
395  32.0  4  135.0  84.00  2295.0  11.6  82  1              "dodge rampage"
396  28.0  4  120.0  79.00  2625.0  18.6  82  1                "ford ranger"
397  31.0  4  119.0  82.00  2720.0  19.4  82  1                 "chevy s-10"

[398 rows x 9 columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use sep

```
pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/\
auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data', sep='\s+')
```

Or

```
df=pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/\
auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!